# How do I format MySQL date to regular US dates

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, formatting

I want to display 2000-12-31 to look like 12/31/2000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looks a little something like this
date('m/d/Y',strtotime($clientsContract['startdate']));

Answer (score 8):

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/mysql/format-date-time-mysql/

> If you wanted to change the format of
>   a MySQL date from YYYY-MM-DD to
>   MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY format you
>   can use the DATE_FORMAT() function as
>   shown in the example below:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d/%m/%Y')
OR
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m/%d/%Y')
```

**EDIT**

Of course, if I read the question properly, I'd tell you how to do it in PHP, like @Stephen did

Comment: I was about to update my answer to include a MySQL solution, so:  great minds think alike?

Answer (score 7):

```
$mysql_date = '2000-12-31';
$formatted_date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($mysql_date));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date("m/d/Y", mktime(0,0,0,12,30,2000))
```

Comment: but then you have to parse out the numbers from the mysql field. strtotime() is better suited for this case.